# How can I add an array to Workbook.Names and refer to it in data validation?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, validation

I have a function that returns an one-dimensional array of strings:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("listOfNames").RefersTo = friendsList("Adam")
```

I want to have this list stored in a Workbook.Names name and this works. But I can't use that then in data validation.

What I use at the moment (and want to get away from) is the following in the names manager:

```
=INDEX(tblFriends;0;1)
```

I cannot get it to work. The result when I store the array is this:

```
={"Peter"\"Kevin"\"Richard"\"Paul"\"Mike"}
```

If I `transpose` only once, then this is the list in the named range (semi-colons due to the language my Excel is in):

```
={"Peter";"Kevin";"Richard";"Paul";"Mike"}
```

But this does not work for the data validation and now I am lost.

Maybe to further explain my problem:
Currently, I use the list in a data validation list dropdown and I am able to choose one value from that list. When I try to do the same but instead of using the reference to a table in a worksheet, I want to be able to use an array directly from VBA. The problem that occurs now: I don't get a list to choose from. The data validation in a sense breaks and when I click on the dropdown, no values are in there.

Comment: Expand on what you want - do you need the array stored differently? Or does it need to be massaged differently to be used by your function. What does "cannot get it to work" mean? Error message returned - or wrong data returned - what should it look like if it DOES work? Keys to a useful question

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've added some more context.